# UIImage change color in specific range

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, cgcontext

May be this question already exists, I tried to find such question, but no luck... So..

For example I have an UIImage:

[image: 1]]

This image has alpha component = 0 (in center and by sides). And I want to remove (make it transparent) specific range of green color, for example let it be right bottom side, result image is:
[image: 2]]

As you can see removed range becomes transparent, if you have any ideas how to do this or some code, please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about use this image as template?

`var image = UIImage(named:"myImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)`

After you can easily apply tint color

Comment: How can I make range of image be transparent with tint color? I think something with CGContextRef will do the trick...